# Can't style slider (or maybe anything) in Material UI

Tags: material-ui

There was [an issue requesting documentation for theming](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/issues/4834) which the author subsequently closed. The author found their answer. A non-programmer will probably not. At least, the non-programmer designer I'm helping doesn't even know where to start (and I still don't have a working different colored slider). This kind of documentation would be great. Even if it's just a link to the code @jdelafon found with some explanation that would suffice to answer the following specific example.

Ultimately, we want a set of sliders with each one a different color. It seems like the appropriate way to do this is with per-element [inline styles](http://www.material-ui.com/#/customization/styles).

I made a simple example [here](http://www.webpackbin.com/VyOppM8LG). Can you change the color of the slider? (We started down the path of breaking out to CSS, but the widget is so dynamic that this approach ends up being quite ugly.)

[Slider](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/slider) has two different slots for theming, neither of which seems to respond to an embedded object with a `selectionColor` key.

Should be simple. Probably it is, but it appears to be undocumented. Otherwise it's a rad UI toolkit, thanks devs!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [this line of `getMuiTheme.js`](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/master/src/styles/getMuiTheme.js#L218). You can find there that `slider` can have those styles overridden:

```
{
  trackSize: 2,
  trackColor: palette.primary3Color,
  trackColorSelected: palette.accent3Color,
  handleSize: 12,
  handleSizeDisabled: 8,
  handleSizeActive: 18,
  handleColorZero: palette.primary3Color,
  handleFillColor: palette.alternateTextColor,
  selectionColor: palette.primary1Color,
  rippleColor: palette.primary1Color,
}
```

In `material-ui` you need to use `MuiThemeProvider` in order to use your custom theme. Taking your example:

```
...
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import getMuiTheme from 'material-ui/styles/getMuiTheme';
import { Slider } from 'material-ui';

const theme1 = getMuiTheme({
  slider: {
    selectionColor: "red",
    trackSize: 20
  }
})

const theme2 = getMuiTheme({
  slider: {
    selectionColor: "green",
    trackSize: 30
  }
})

const HelloWorld = () => (
  <div>
    ...
  <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={theme1}>
    <Slider defaultValue={0.5}/>
  </MuiThemeProvider>
  <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={theme2}>
    <Slider defaultValue={0.5}/>
  </MuiThemeProvider>
  </div>
);

export default HelloWorld;
```

Your modified webpackbin: http://www.webpackbin.com/EyEPnZ_8M

The `sliderStyle` you tried to use is for different styles :-) Like `marginTop` / `marginBottom`, a [full list can be found here](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/master/src/Slider/Slider.js#L149).